# Bare minimum necessary for a single Jersey GET resource?

Tags: rest, tomcat, jersey

I am missing something obvious, but I'm not sure what.  I have a single "HelloWorld.java" that has a single @GET method that returns some text.

My web.xml was taken from [this doc](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4867/ggnxs?l=en&a=view) (described as "An even simpler approach is to let Jersey choose the PackagesResourceConfig implementation automatically...."):

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.hello.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

Here's my class (mostly taken from [here](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4867/ggnxo?l=en&a=view)):

```
package com.hello.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorld {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/json")
    public String getHelloWorld() {
        return "{\"hello\":\"World\"}";
    }
}
```

I use ant to build a war file, and deploy it to tomcat.  The war appears correct because tomcat unzips it and I can access my static index.html that I put in it for testing.  But accessing localhost:8080/helloworld gives me a 404.  There must be some other piece I need in order to get Jersey working.  What did I miss?

Thank you Bozho, I was missing the `<servlet-mapping>` section.  Actually it appears I don't want a "/" as url-pattern, because that prevents serving static content (I can't get my index.html page any more!) so here's my new web.xml (I put my resource in the "/data/" path):

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.hello.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/data/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now I can access my index.html page as `http://localhost:8080/hello/index.html`, and my resource at `http://localhost:8080/hello/data/helloworld`.

Comment: `hello` should also be surrounded by double quotes as for the JSON spec...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to map your servlet with `<servlet-mapping>`, with a `/` as `url-pattern`